# Is repeating the action/verb in a metaphor a sign that is a bad one?

Tags: creative-writing, metaphor

Example:

> She didn’t reply; just **stared** at us vacantly.
>   She might as well have been **observing** two squirrels that had invaded
>   her yard.

As you can see, the action **stare/observe** has so be repeated for the metaphor to work. Is that a sign of a bad metaphor?

Should I write this instead?

> She didn’t reply; just **stared** at us vacantly.
>   I suddenly felt as if we were two squirrels that had invaded
>   her yard.

Comment: Actually, these seem to be more of similes than metaphors...

Comment: @SF. I think a simile is a type of metaphor: https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailywritingtips.com%2Fwhat-is-the-difference-between-metaphor-and-simile%2F&ei=fddZVMesJNXf8AWk8YCICw&usg=AFQjCNEk0jeJRtWa0X8bLMrZV7SlBeoazA&sig2=3xyAvAJNCeYnOdF1_UnEAw&bvm=bv.78677474,d.dGc

Comment: That article really muddles the matter which is quite simple. A simile is not a type of metaphor. A simile frequently *uses* a metaphor as one side of a comparison.

Comment: ...also, I wouldn't say such repeating makes it a *bad* simile. It certainly makes it weaker, less expressive, but I wouldn't go as far as "bad".

Comment: A simile is an **explicit comparison**, often with comparative particle ("as", "like"): "Thou art more lovely than a summer day". Think of the sentence as a mathematical formula: you > summer day, or: we = squirrels. In a metaphor, one structural relation is **replaced** by another: (a) light provides warmth and illumination, (b) love provides emotional well-being, => metaphor: "Lolita, light of my life, ...".

Comment: How about: *We might as well have been squirrels gathering acorns in her yard, for all she cared.*  Or change the ownership of the metaphor: *I've paid closer attention to squirrels rummaging in my yard.*  (Although, personally I find squirrels funny and interesting, and like to watch them.  So your metaphor/simile doesn't work too well for me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that a sign of a bad metaphor?

No. It's fine.

And of course you're the author - it's up to you what you write. From this point of view there are no 'bad' metaphors.

But I know what you mean and no, your example would not usually be considered poor English usage.

You may be thinking of [(in-)elegant variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegant_variation) or [pleonasm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm).